# How to request specific video quality link with Vimeo API php library?

Tags: php, vimeo-api

I am having exactly the same issue as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48814094/request-specific-video-quality-with-vimeo-api-php-library) where the array entries are random but I want to select a specific entry. As this is the only way to get the 2k and 4k links I'm unsure of the intended way of getting them. That question is very old and has a good answer but I am just wondering if this is still the case?

Currently I am trying to use array_filter() to sort the response but I'm not sure if its the best approach.

Comment: Taking a brief look at the [api](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/reference/response/video/3.4), a `files` array is still returned, so yes, it appears that is still the current approach.

Answer (score 0):

It's a shame I couldn't add this to the other question because I would have liked to get the other users opinion on this but below is what I've ended up doing. There's probably a better way to do it, if so I'm interested in hearing it.

```
public static function getVideoData($newVideoId, $videoResolution) {
  $client = new Vimeo('{client_id}', '{client_secret}', '{access_token}');
  $response = $client->request('/videos/'.$newVideoId, array(), 'GET');
  $body = $response['body'];

  if(isset($body['error'])){
    var_dump($body['error']);
  } else {
    //Thumbnail link
    $filteredSizesArray = array_filter($body['pictures']['sizes'], function($element) {
       return $element['width'] === 1920;
    });
    $sizesArray = array_values($filteredSizesArray);
    $thumbnailLink = $sizesArray[0]['link'];

    //File link
    $filteredResolutionArray = array_filter($body['files'], function($element) use($videoResolution){
       return $element['public_name'] === $videoResolution;
    });
    $resolutionArray = array_values($filteredResolutionArray);
    $fileLink = $resolutionArray[0]['link'];

    return array('fileLink' => $fileLink, 'thumbnailLink' => $thumbnailLink);
  }
}
```

Comment: Feel free to add a link in a comment on the other question if you feel that this helps

Comment: Unfortunately I can't comment because I don't have enough reputation. It's OK I'm reasonably happy with this solution and hopefully it helps others. Still keen to hear any better solutions or ways to improve though.

Comment: One bit of advice I can offer for this site is to make your code stand the test of time and be reusable as much as possible. For instance, your code is `public static` which implies a class, but that class is not shown. You could show the class, but since you aren’t referencing other static methods or properties, the fact that it is a class is an abstraction unrelated to the problem. Some people get it, others don’t, and least common denominator often wins here. No right or wrong, just assume people will copy your code verbatim in 10 years and say ‘’it isn’t working”. Less code is easier.

Comment: I take your point, thanks Chris.